# Copying a Partition-Empty Sectors and All

Tags: backup, restore, gparted, sectors

What's the best way to copy a entire partition empty sectors and all as to recover deleted files, a few have recommended "dd" but I'll be honest I've never used it and nobody seems to know of a simple how to on the topic. I attempted using gparted but after copying a partition that had only 3 gigs of data on it and found it took less than 2 minutes to copy the partition quickly realized it does not copy empty sectors as few have told me.

So I was wondering if anybody has a how to on how to use dd to copy a partition empty sectors and all, or of anything like gparted (being as a bootable disc format) that indeed copies bit by bit, empty sectors included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A howto for `dd` seems unneeded since it is a very simple command.

`dd if=/dev/sda2 of=my_full_partition_backup bs=1M` would copy partition number 2 on the first disk to a file called  my_full_partition_backup. You just need source (if) and destination (of), though adding `bs=1M` is advice for a huge speed gain.

If you want to copy a full disk (not just a partition) use `/dev/sda`. No number. sdA for the first disk, sdB for the second disk, sdC for the third disk etc etc.

If you are doing this as a backup then you might want to compress the result. You can do this after you made the image (e.g. run dd, then bzip the result, or during the backup. The last will make the backup slower, but you need less disk space.

To do the latter use
`dd if=/dev/sda2 bs=1M | gzip > my_full_partition_backup.gz`

Comment: Ok so just to confirm, this will copy the empty sectors as well, not to second guess you, but I'm in slight panic mode right now and need to make sure I can get a backup of the "deleted" content as well so that I can restore it.

Comment: Size is no problem, I have multiple hard drives, although I am going to restore it onto another drive the same size as well so am I correct to assume, by do the latter you mean restore all information in my_full_partition_backup.gz onto another disk in bootable form.

Also the terminal in the gparted live should be able to do the dd correct?

Comment: Data recovery and few other things. Oh and so would it be correct to assume that dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M would just do full drive to drive instead of just the 1 partition.

Comment: Correct me I'm wrong, I'm hoping that command works but I don't want t attempt anything without consulting those who know more about it first.

Comment: THANK YOU, so I'm correct to assume the terminal in gparted will work the same, correct, you never responded to that question.

Comment: Should I have mentioned the OS on sda is vista? Found the wiki on dd and made me wonder, yes I'm new to dd.

Comment: The OS should not matter. Dd will read and write data without trying to parse it. Compare it to a xerox copying a page of text. It does not have to understand the language just to make a copy.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering as I got a dd: opening '/dev/sda':permission denied

Comment: Are you booting from the same disk as you are trying to copy?  (Hint, do not do that, use a live CD)

Comment: I am using the gparted live disc.

Comment: Hen, when you wake up, dd finished this time, but when I refreshed gparted to check, all the partitions are the right size, but it's registering them all as empty.

Comment: Checked the information for the partitions, Warning, the device /dev/sdb2 doesn't exist. ntfsresize v2oo12.1.15ar.1 (libntfs-3g) error(2):failed to check '/dev/sdb2' mount state no such file or directory

Probably /etc/mtab is missing. It's too risky to continue. You might try an another linux distro. Unable to read the contents of this 
file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable.

The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support : ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g.